# clean url's managed in frontend without hashtag

Tags: javascript, html, apache, .htaccess, web

I want to have urls like example.com/amsterdam, I know you can do it like this example.com/#/amsterdam.

But I don't want the /#/ part in my URL. I think I need to modify my .htaccess for this but I did not found a good example over the internet for this.

What I would like is when somebody navigating to example.com/amsterdam 
I want it to go to the homepage where I can handle the /amsterdam via javascript so I can show the amsterdam text on the homepage and put the example.com/amsterdam in my sitemap.xml for google.

I tried my best to explain this. If you have any hunch of how to get this done please don't hesitate to respond

Comment: That solution was for the backend and totally different. I want to manage it in the frontend, I get the htaccess fallback but what then?

Comment: Right, you mentioned ".htaccess" after "frontend", so I posted the wrong thing. You need Javascript and `history.push()`.

Comment: Is it possible that you show an example and post it as an answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, this was hard to get working but I did it the following way.

I added the following line to my .htaccess`FallbackResource index.php` To do this make sure you are on a newer version of apache as this is relatively a new function of apache. What this does is when it doesnt find the page you requested for it goes to the index.php page instead of standard 404 of apache.

Then, i added a index.php page where i had the following code

```
$whitelist = [
    "Rotterdam",
    "Amsterdam",
];

$cwhitelist = [];

foreach ($whitelist as $key => $value) {
    array_push($cwhitelist,strtolower($value));
}

$urlpath = strtolower(basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
$inarr = in_array($urlpath,$cwhitelist);
if(!$inarr){
    $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if($actual_link != "https://www.slotenmakergroep.nl/"){
            if( $actual_link != "http://www.slotenmakergroep.nl/"){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["link"] = $actual_link;
                header("Location: 404.php",true,301);
            }

    }
}
```

What this does is the following, i have a whitelist array of whitelisted links i approve and then make them all lowercase.

After that i take the url  and the text after the slash and check if that text is in the array. if it is in the array i also check if its a http link or https link.

And to finish if the link is not in the whitelist i send them to a 404.php page and in the session i save what link they tried to access.